# SVG Zoom Issue Desktop vs Mobile with leaflet.js

Tags: svg, mobile, leaflet, zooming

I've tried to use [leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/) to allow user to zoom and pan on big SVG files on my website. I've used the following [script](http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html) to display the SVG with leaflet :

```
    // Using leaflet.js to pan and zoom a big image.
    // See also: http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html
    var factor = 1;
    
    // create the slippy map
    var map = L.map('image-map', {
        minZoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 5,
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });

    function getMeta(url) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var w = this.naturalWidth;
            var h = this.naturalHeight;
            var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
            var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
            var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);


            // add the image overlay, 
            // so that it covers the entire map
            L.imageOverlay(img.src, bounds).addTo(map);

            // tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
            map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
            map.fitBounds(bounds); // test

        });
        img.src = url;
    }

    getMeta("/assets/images/bhikkhu-patimokkha.svg")
```

You can see the result [here](https://fractalcitta.github.io/assets/maps/bhikkhu-patimokkha.html). The probleme is that it works fine on my iPhone, the zoom level are approriate and it is easy to zoom in, but on the desktop version, you can only zoom out and not in.

I've tried to change the **minZoom: 1** to different values, but it dosen't seem to do anything. The only way I was able to make it work on desktop was to add a multiplicating factor 10 to **var w** and **var h**, but then it would screw up on the mobile version.

I had more sucess with PNG images, but they are very slow to load. Maybe the code is inapropriate for SVG and particularly when calling **naturalHeight** ? But it looked fined when I debbuged it.

Thanks for your help.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/fractalcitta/pen/NWawEyr) to play around if you want.

EDIT : Using the nicer code from @Grzegorz T. It works well on Desktop now. but on Safari iOS it is overzoomed and cannot unzoom... see picture below (it was working with the previous code on Iphone but not on Destop...)

[image: iphone capture]

Comment: Try a negative number, e.g. `minZoom: -4` I know strange, but it works for me - [image-instead-of-map](https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#07.image-instead-of-map)

Comment: @Grzegorz T. thank you, I've tried different values as you mentionned. So far min-zoom = 1 and max-zoom = 0 gives an interensting result, but cannot zoom in either. Negative min-zoom don't seem to work. I've made a codepen to play around in my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the variables `w` and `h` you will see what small variables are returned. To increase them I increased them by `* 5` for this I used fitBounds and it should now scale to the viewer window and at the same time it is possible to zoom.

To be able to also click more than once on the zoom, I changed `map.getMaxZoom () - 1` to `map.getMaxZoom () - 2`

```
var map = L.map("image-map", {
  minZoom: 1, // tried 0.1,-4,...
  maxZoom: 4,
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});

function getMeta(url) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var w = this.naturalWidth * 5;
    var h = this.naturalHeight * 5;

    var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom() - 2);
    var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 2);
    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

    // add the image overlay,
    // so that it covers the entire map
    L.imageOverlay(img.src, bounds).addTo(map);

    // tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
    // map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  img.src = url;
}

getMeta("https://fractalcitta.github.io/assets/images/bhikkhu-patimokkha.svg");
```

You don't need to increase `(w, h) * 5` but just change to `map.getMaxZoom () - 4`

And one more important thing that you should always do with svg, which is optimizing these files.
I always use this site - [svgomg](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

**Second version width async/promise** ----------

```
let map = L.map("map", {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 4,
});

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
    img.addEventListener("error", reject);
    img.src = url;
  });
}

async function getImageData(url) {
  const img = await loadImage(url);
  return { img, width: img.naturalWidth, height: img.naturalHeight };
}

async function showOnMap(url) {
  const { img, width, height } = await getImageData(url);

  const southWest = map.unproject([0, height], map.getMaxZoom() - 4);
  const northEast = map.unproject([width, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 4);

  const bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  L.imageOverlay(img.src, bounds).addTo(map);

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

showOnMap(
  "https://fractalcitta.github.io/assets/images/bhikkhu-patimokkha.svg"
);
```

**The third approach to the problem, I hope the last one ;)**

You need a little description of what's going on here.
We get svg by featch we inject into hidden div which has `width/height` set to `0`
Then we use the [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) property to get the exact dimensions from that injected svg.

I am not using `map.unproject` in this example. To have the exact dimensions of bounds it is enough that:

```
const bounds = [
  [0, 0], // padding
  [width, height], // image dimensions
];
```

All code below:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="svg" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 0;"></div>
```

```
let map = L.map("map", {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  minZoom: -4,
  maxZoom: 1,
});

const url =
  "https://fractalcitta.github.io/assets/images/bhikkhu-patimokkha.svg";

async function fetchData(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.text();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

fetchData(url)
  .then((svg) => {
    const map = document.getElementById("svg");
    map.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", svg);
  })
  .then(() => {
    const svgElement = document.getElementById("svg");
    const { width, height } = svgElement.firstChild.getBBox();
    return { width, height };
  })
  .then(({ width, height }) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = url;

    const bounds = [
      [0, 0], // padding
      [width, height], // image dimensions
    ];

    L.imageOverlay(img.src, bounds).addTo(map);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I've edit my question with a screenshot from my iphone using your second version. It is overzoomed on it and cannot unzoomed. The previous code was fine on iphone.
But your code works well on Desktop. Maybe I can use JS to detect mobile device and change code accordinlgy.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to test it on the iPhone because I do not have it ;) 
Debug the page on your phone. It is possible by connecting an [Android](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) device to Windows. Maybe there is a similar way to debug the page by connecting an iPhone to a Mac, but which, unfortunately, I do not know.

Comment: One more note, naturalWidth/Heigh does not work under FF, bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700533
Here the svg problem is described https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3510#issuecomment-369982529
It follows that it is best to hard-set bounds if it is possible.

Comment: OK, I've tried to connect my iphone to see and it gives  height = 1354 much bigger than on Chrome Desktop (=150). And actually it is the same behaviour with Safari Desktop. So your are right the naturalWidth/Height gives different values depending on the browser. I will try a few things. If nothing works I will defined the dimensions for each svg that I load, but it would be nice to have a function that return dimension consistently on each browser.

Comment: Ok thank you for third approch. I've tried it and get the error : "svgElement.getBBox is not a function". it needs .firstChild before getBBox() as svgElement is not the svg but the parent div#svg. I solved it here https://codepen.io/fractalcitta/pen/dyVZxpy. Brilliant, it worked very well on mobile and Safari as well. thanks

Comment: That's right, because the original svg was to go directly to svg, not `id=svg`. And then I corrected it on getElementById but I did not add firstChild ;) I will correct it in the example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so finally I used the code from @Grzegorz T. with a small modification. Adding a const H = 100; that play the role of an arbitrary height and then the width W is calculated using the ratio of dimensions given by the browers. (ratio are the same, dimension of SVG are differents on different browsers)

Here is the code :

```
const W = 100; // this allow to get the correct ratio 
               // then it dosen't depend on browser giving different dimentions.

    let map = L.map("image-map", {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 4,
    });

    function loadImage(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
            img.addEventListener("error", reject);
            img.src = url;
        });
    }

    async function getImageData(url) {
        const img = await loadImage(url);
        return { img, width: img.naturalWidth, height: img.naturalHeight };
    }

    async function showOnMap(url) {
        const { img, width, height } = await getImageData(url);

        const H = W * width / height; // hopefuly height is not = 0 (mozilla ?)

        const southWest = map.unproject([0, H], map.getMaxZoom() - 4);
        const northEast = map.unproject([W, 0], map.getMaxZoom() - 4);

        const bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
        L.imageOverlay(img.src, bounds).addTo(map);

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    showOnMap(
        "https://fractalcitta.github.io/assets/images/bhikkhu-patimokkha.svg"
    );
```

Comment: I added a third version and probably the final solution, svg dimensions are read correctly in every browser, maybe except IE ;) Test it on safari but it should be ok.